# how to import table from rdbms to hive using sqoop in hadoop cluster?

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to import table from RDBMS to HIVE using SQOOP in hadoop cluster, i am getting the following error, can you please provide the solution for this.

```
bin/sqoop-import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoop -username root -password root --table salaries  --hive-table salaries --create-hive-table --hive-import --hive-home  /home/techgene/hive-0.11.0 -m 1 --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse
```

Exception:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
14/06/02 14:30:19 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:364)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:314)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:226)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:415)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:476)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever ,you are using a Sqoop with Hive import option,the sqoop connects directly the corresponding the database's metastore and gets the corresponding table 's metadata(the table's schema),so there is no need to create a table structure in Hive.This schema is then provided to the Hive when used with Hive-import option.

**Example::

```
**sudo sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.57/movielens --username root --password root —hive-import**
```

this is too import the tables from movielens database in mysql.
￼

```
**sqoop import \
   --connect jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.57/movielens \
   --username root \
   --password hadoop \
   --table cities \
  --hive-import**
```

**this is to just import one table called cities.****

So the output of all the sqoop data on HDFS will by default stored in the default directory .i.e **`/user/sqoop/tablename/part-m`** files

with hive import option,the tables will be downloaded directly into the default warehouse direcotry i.e.

**`/user/hive/warehouse/tablename`**

**command : `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls -R /user/`** 
this lists recursively all the files with in the user.

Now go to Hive and type show databases.if there is only default database, then type show tables: 
**remember OK is common default system output and is not part of the command output.**

```
hive> show databases;

OK

default

Time taken: 0.172 seconds

hive> show tables;

OK

genre

log_apache

movie

moviegenre

movierating

occupation

user

Time taken: 0.111 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the syntax, eliminate extra spaces..

```
$ sqoop-import --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoop;database=< db_name >" 
               -username root 
               -password root 
               --table salaries 
               --hive-import 
               --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse
```

No need to mention `--hive-table < table_name >` if using the same name as in mysql